# Quisiera visualizar los datos de la línea que se crea con Geom_smooth

Tags: r, rstudio

```
PAP = ggplot(PAP, aes(x = AÑO, y = PRECIPITACION)) + 
      geom_line() + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm") 

PAP = PAP + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) + 
      theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0)) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1945, 1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015,2020))+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 8))
```

Este es el código que tengo para gráficar, pero necesito visualizar los datos de la línea de tendencia que se genera con "geom_smooth"

Comment: ¿Y que problema tienes? ¿No veo que tengas nada mal en tu código, la recta de regresión debiera verse bien? ¿Puedes compartir una muestra de los datos?